# Own layerswitcher value not defined

Tags: openlayers-2, html

I am trying to write my own layerswitcher because I want a dropdown box (and later a second one)

My Webinspector says: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined` 
but I cannot find what is wrong. In my opinion it is defined.
Thanks to everyone trying to help me.

Here is the code:

```
<div id="map"></div>
<!--<div id="external_control"style="font-size:16px; padding:10px;border:1px solid black;background-color:grey;width:250px;height:100px;"></div>-->
<script>
    function auswahlLayer1(element){
             if(element.value == "Einwohner"){
                overlayEnergieverbrauch.setVisibility(false);
                overlayEinwohner.setVisibility(true);
             }
             if(element.value == "Energieverbrauch"){
                overlayEinwohner.setVisibility(false);
                overlayEnergieverbrauch.setVisibility(true);
             }
    }
</script>
<div id="control" >
<select onchange="auswahlLayer1()">
        <option value="Einwohner">Einwohner</option>
        <option value="Energieverbrauch">Energieverbrauch</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a closer look:

```
<select onchange="auswahlLayer1()">
```

You are calling `auswahlLayer1()` without any parameters (therefore, `element` is undefined and `element.value` throws error). Try

```
<select onchange="auswahlLayer1(this)">
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, ist was the first part to my solution. I worked on that part but now i have the next error :-(

Answer (score 0):

I changed a few things but now I have another problem.
The Webinspector says auswahlLayer1 is not defined.
I don't understand it because I believe I have defined it, the code now looks like this :

```
<script>
    function auswahlLayer1(element){
            document.getElementById("Einwohner")setVisibility(false);
            document.getElementById("Energieverbrauch").setVisibility(false);
            var value = element.options[element.selectedIndex].value; 
             if(value == "Einwohner"){
                console.log("Einwohner");
                document.getElementById("Einwohner").setVisibility(true);

             }
             if(value == "Energieverbrauch"){
                document.getElementById("Energieverbrauch").setVisibility(true);
             }
            }
    </script>
    <div id="control" >
    <form action="select.htm">
        <select name="Auswahl1" size="1" onchange="auswahlLayer1(this)">
            <option value="Einwohner">Einwohner</option>
            <option value="Energieverbrauch">Energieverbrauch</option>

        </select>
    </form>
    </div>
```

Comment: You should post this as separate question. And also you should add point behind ("Einwohner") and setVisibility :)